# Constraining XPath sibling relationships using preceding and following

Tags: xml, xpath, siblings

I am in need of understanding how I would create an XPath to return only id values for the root_level elements with a value of 2 that immediately follow a root_level 1 value. I have spent several hours on the site reviewing prior responses to similar posts but they don't have the same type of constraints I am encountering.

Here is an example XML snippet. They can be **much** longer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <result>
            <item>
                <id>659478</id>
                <name>Company A</name>
                <root_level>1</root_level>
                </item>
            <item>
                <id>692557</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>659482</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>666534</id>
                <root_level>3</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>665260</id>
                <root_level>3</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>665773</id>
                <root_level>3</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>635003</id>
                <name>Company B</name>
                <root_level>1</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>635005</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>635015</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>671626</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>584793</id>
                <name>Company C</name>
                <root_level>1</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>623716</id>
                <root_level>2</root_level>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>698585</id>
                <root_level>3</root_level>
            </item>
    </result>
```

I have tried variants of the following XPath but this requires always knowing the next root_level 1 name. Note that there also may be no following root_level 3 values. The only constant is a root_level 1 always exists.

```
//item[root_level=2][preceding-sibling::item[name='Company A'] and following-sibling::item[name='Company B']]/id
```

Additionally, I am forced to use XPath 1.0 in my solution.

If someone could point me in the right direction to constraining the root_level 2 results returned to only match those pertaining to a specific root_level 1 name based on the descendancy order, I would be most appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: What would be the desired output, for instance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would want just the id values for the correct root_level 2 item elements, so for 'Company A':

692557
659482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way to return all *root-level-2 id* elements that corresponds to certain *company*, i.e `'Company A'` :

```
//item[root_level=2][preceding-sibling::item[root_level=1][1][name='Company A']]/id
```

- `//item[root_level=2]`: find all root-level-2 `<item>`...
- `[preceding-sibling::item[name][1][name='Company A']]`: ...having nearest preceding sibling root-level-1 `<name>` equals `"Company A"`
- `/id` : then return the `<id>` child element

Comment: Thanks for that and for the explanation about how the position value works with preceding-sibling. That was definitely a light bulb going off moment...